# Dúvida sobre Criptografia em passwords

Tags: php, login, md5, password, sha-256

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença do MD5 para o SHA256 nas passwords.
Se existe um mais seguro e qual e quando é melhor usar um ou outro.

Answer (score 0):

Ambos são algoritmos de hashing, porêm o MD5 atualmente é considerado quebrado, isto é, não é recomendado seu uso.

SHA256 é um pouco mais seguro que o MD5 e SHA1 (também considerado quebrado), porém também não é ideal para utilizar em senhas. Uns dos principais motivos são porque SHA256 assim como MD5 são feitos para serem rápidos e são bastante vulneráveis a rainbow tables.

Atualmente uma das soluções é utilizar um algoritmo lento e de preferência utilizar um salt. O PHP a partir da versão 5.6 suporta nativamente o BCRYPT e se não me engano a partir da versão 7.2 também suporta o ARGON2 que são algoritmos excelentes para hashing de senhas.

Para utiliza-los, existem as funções password_hash() e password_verify().

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php